# Web scraping from continuous URLs using R

Tags: r

I am trying to scrap data from a website which lists the ratings of multiple products. So, let's say a product has 800 brands. So, with 10 brands per page, I will need to scrap data from 8 pages. Eg: Here is the data for baby care. There are 24 pages worth of brands that I need - http://www.goodguide.com/products?category_id=152775-baby-care&sort_order=DESC#!rf%3D%26rf%3D%26rf%3D%26cat%3D152775%26page%3D**1**%26filter%3D%26sort_by_type%3Drating%26sort_order%3DDESC%26meta_ontology_node_id%3D

I have used the bold font for 1, as that is the only thing that changes in this url as we move from page to page. So, I thought it might be straight forward to write a loop in R. But what I find is that as I move to page 2, the page does not load again. Instead, just the results are updated in about 5 secs. However, R does not wait for 5 seconds and thus, I had the data from the first page 26 times.

I also tried entering the page 2 url directly and ran my code without a loop. Same story- I got page 1 results. I am sure I can't be the only one facing this. Any help is appreciated. I have attached the code.

Thanks a million. And I hope my question was clear enough.

```
# build the URL

N<-matrix(NA,26,15)
R<-matrix(NA,26,60)

for(n in 1:26){

url <- paste("http://www.goodguide.com/products?category_id=152775-baby-care&sort_order=DESC#!rf%3D%26rf%3D%26rf%3D%26cat%3D152775%26page%3D",i,"%26filter%3D%26sort_by_type%3Drating%26sort_order%3DDESC%26meta_ontology_node_id%3D")


raw.data <-readLines(url)

Parse <- htmlParse(raw.data)

#####
A<-querySelector(Parse, "div.results-container")

#####
Name<-querySelectorAll(A,"div.reviews>a")
Ratings<-querySelectorAll(A,"div.value")

N[n,]<-sapply(Name,function(x)xmlGetAttr(x,"href"))
R[n,]<-sapply(Ratings,xmlValue)
}
```

Comment: You could always do a [Sys.sleep](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.sleep.html) between calls. That's what I ended up doing to grab data from Qualys Labs' [SSL Tester](http://datadrivensecurity.info/blog/posts/2014/Apr/scraping-ssl-server-test-results-with-r/).

Comment: Your iterator is `n`, but you're pasting `i` when constructing your url.

Comment: Thanks jbaums, corrected it and still does not work :(

Comment: (Yep, I didn't mean to suggest that was your only problem ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the html source reveals that the urls you want can be simplified to this structure:

`http://www.goodguide.com/products?category_id=152775-baby-care&page=2&sort_orde‌​r=DESC.`

The content of these urls is retrieved by R as expected.

Note that you can also go straight to:

```
u <- sprintf('http://www.goodguide.com/products?category_id=152775-baby-car‌​e&page=%s&sort_order=DESC', n)
Parse <- htmlParse(u)
```

Comment: It worked :) Thanks. Would you mind telling me how you figured out the html source for page 2. I'm extremely new to this and want to learn. Sorry about so many questions.

Comment: @user3728332: I got a bit lucky, I guess - I searched the source for 'page' and 'pagination'. I think the page buttons add some GET parameters to the raw url on the fly, and it's probably the filtering that causes the page to stutter like that.